# failed to give absolute path in python

Tags: python

Im trying to give absolute path like this:

```
data_dir = "C:/Users/haimb/birds_implementation/birds"

train_dir = data_dir + "/train"

test_dir = data_dir + "/test"

embeddings_path_train = train_dir + "/char-CNN-RNN-embeddings.pickle"

embeddings_path_test = test_dir + "/char-CNN-RNN-embeddings.pickle"

filename_path_train = train_dir + "/filenames.pickle"

filename_path_test = test_dir + "/filenames.pickle"

class_id_path_train = train_dir + "/class_info.pickle"

class_id_path_test = test_dir + "/class_info.pickle"

dataset_path = "C:/Users/haimb/birds_implementation/CUB_200_2011"
```

and after this i want to call this function:

```
def train_stage1(self):
      """Trains the stage1 StackGAN.
    """
      x_train, y_train, train_embeds = load_data(filename_path=filename_path_train, class_id_path=class_id_path_train,
      dataset_path=dataset_path, embeddings_path=embeddings_path_train, size=(64, 64))

      x_test, y_test, test_embeds = load_data(filename_path=filename_path_test, class_id_path=class_id_path_test, 
      dataset_path=dataset_path, embeddings_path=embeddings_path_test, size=(64, 64))
```

all of the above code is inside "class StackGanStage1(object):" in train_stage1 method

My problem is when i call

```
stage1 = StackGanStage1()
stage1.train_stage1()
```

I got the following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-34644e9acffb> in <module>()
      1 stage1 = StackGanStage1()
----> 2 stage1.train_stage1()

<ipython-input-53-3a9537aeb97f> in train_stage1(self)
     65       """Trains the stage1 StackGAN.
     66     """
---> 67       x_train, y_train, train_embeds = load_data(filename_path=filename_path_train, class_id_path=class_id_path_train,
     68       dataset_path=dataset_path, embeddings_path=embeddings_path_train, size=(64, 64))
     69 

NameError: name 'filename_path_train' is not defined
```

Its seems that the paths that I pass in the beginning are not right, can anyone can tell me how to fix this please?

**Edit: now after I added self. before its works, but still something with the path is wrong:**

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py:105: UserWarning: The `lr` argument is deprecated, use `learning_rate` instead.
  super(Adam, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-34644e9acffb> in <module>()
      1 stage1 = StackGanStage1()
----> 2 stage1.train_stage1()

2 frames
<ipython-input-9-daee48aa8b58> in load_class_ids_filenames(class_id_path, filename_path)
     20 
     21 def load_class_ids_filenames(class_id_path, filename_path):
---> 22         with open(class_id_path, 'rb') as file:
     23                 class_id = pickle.load(file, encoding='latin1')
     24 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/haimb/birds_implementation/birds/train/class_info.pickle'
```

Any suggestations?
Thanks you

Comment: "all of the above code is inside "class StackGanStage1(object):" in train_stage1 method" THen you should put that in the block of code instead of explaining it in English.

Comment: Aside, the `os.path.join()` function is a more robust / portable solution than string concatenation, for file paths.

Comment: @S3DEV: Or for more fluent path manipulation, use `pathlib.Path` (`os.path.join(a, b, c)` being expressed as `pathlib.Path(a) / b / c`, using the native host directory separators the same way).

Comment: @ShadowRanger - Yes, fair point, thank you.  (Personally, I just can’t get my head around the `pathlib` syntax construct, it feels so ‘foreign’.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're taking self as a parameter, I'm assuming 'filename_path_train' is defined inside that class, since you're trying to access self, the basic fix should be self.filename_path_train that is because you're tryinig to access that objects filename_path_train, and that goes on for every parameter defined inside that class.

Comment: Alternatively you can do `StackGanStage1. filename_path_train`.

Comment: Edit: now after I added self. before its works, but still something with the path is wrong:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).